# What is the difference between HTML attribute `disabled` and `inert`?

Tags: html

I am trying to figure the difference between inert and disabled `html` attribute , apart from the specific nature of the `disabled` attribute that only specific element can use it. Does it mean `inert` is a kind of `disabled` that works on all element?

```
<div inert>
  <button>This is a button</button>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="button" value="This is an input">
</div>
<div>
  <button disabled>This is a button</button>
  <input type="text" disabled>
  <input type="button" value="This is an input" disabled>
</div>
<div>
  <button>This is a button</button>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="button" value="This is an input">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`disabled`* and *`inert`* have completely different purposes. *`disabled`* is an actual attribute, while *`inert`* is merely a definition of the concept it describes.

The purpose of using *`disabled`* is to keep a user from interacting with and submitting the value of an `input` element and is supported solely on such elements.

On the other hand, *`inert`* can be used on any element and it's used to instruct the user agent to act as if the marked node were absent for the purposes of targeting user interaction events.

[Here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert) is what the `HTML` standard says about *`inert`*:

> When a node is inert, then the user agent must act as if the node was absent for the purposes of targeting user interaction events, may ignore the node for the purposes of text search user interfaces (commonly known as “find in page”), and may prevent the user from selecting text in that node.

In addition, the standard has the following two notes regarding *`inert`*:

> 1. When a node is inert, it generally cannot be focused. Inert nodes that are commands will also get disabled.
> 2. This section does not define or create any content attribute named "inert". This section merely defines an abstract concept of inertness.

Comment: Why do you say they are irrelevant?   They are not at all irrelevant, they are both very useful indeed.

Comment: I never said they're not useful, @John. I said they're distinct and irrelevant towards one another.

Comment: Ah, I think I see - perhaps you mean "unrelated to each other", rather than "irrelevant".   Something that's irrelevant cannot be useful! :)

Comment: Thanks, @teraspora. My English wasn't as good back then. Reading the answer now, I realise how it can be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no HTML attribute `inert`.

From the (current as of today) WHATWG HTML specification text:

> This section does not define or create any content attribute named "inert". This section merely defines an abstract concept of inertness.

See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert-subtrees (*HTML Standard - Section 6.2 Inert subtrees*)

Comment: Wrong.   `inert` is an HTML Global Attribute, as specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert

Comment: @John *inert* is *now* an HTML attribute as of the current WHATWG spec indeed, but it wasn't at the time the question was asked. Btw MDN while useful is *not* reference information; instead, WHATWG's "living standard" HTML spec ... lives at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/ and the first snapshot to contain *inert* is HTML Review Draft published January, 2023 at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/review-drafts/2023-01/